# ASP.NET MVC urls for subsites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In my Views I have urls mapped like `/My/Urls.something`, for example in links (when I don't use View helpers), including static content like images, and mostly in javascript code (Ajax calls and the like).

This works fine when I deploy my app in a first level domain, like `http://mysite.com/` because the `/` before the Url remaps it to the root of the domain, but if the site is deployed as a subsite, for example `http://mysite.com/myapp/`, this doesn't worka anymore, and omitting the `/` (for example `/My/Urls.something` -> `My/Urls.something`) doesn't work in inner pages like `http://mysite.com/myapp/admin` where I want to read `http://mysite.com/myapp/My/Urls.something` but I get `http://mysite.com/myapp/admin/My/Urls.something`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use view helpers.  Even if you don't want to use the ActionLink helper, you should use the Url.Action helper to generate your url.  Why?  Because of the very problem you're trying to solve, which the helpers were designed to fix.

For example:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" />
```

Comment: what when i don't want to link an action but an image or a javascript file?

Comment: Well, you could run it through an action method, and return a File result.  That way you can control access to the file.  Or, you can take the resulting path from an action method, strip off the end bit and put your filename in.